# Why do some power transistors emit light?

Tags: light, physics

I am specifically looking for an image I believe I have seen before so I can link it to a friend. It was a TO-3 packaged device with the metal cap removed, showing a power device emitting light as a side effect.

I seem to remember it being a BJT, maybe even one of the common variety (2n3055). Have any of you heard of this phenomenon? Can you explain why it occurs? If you can link to an image of this, I would be very grateful.

---

EDIT

This is one of the links I was looking for 
https://lab.whitequark.org/notes/2014-06-14/transistor-as-a-light-source/

Comment: Through some research, I have found that it is due to avalanche conditions, and can occur in diodes as well.

Comment: Most of my prototype circuit emit light (then smoke) when I wire them up backwards.

Comment: In old textbooks I've seen microscope photos of MOSFET dies emitting infrared.   During linear operation (pinch-off) the FET channel is experiencing constant avalanche breakdown, and it emits a tiny bit of IR light.

Comment: all power transistors emit light if you run them hot enough

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a [hot carrier avalanche](http://www.jeldev.org/1TOUFIK.pdf) condition. Normally a Si junction would not emit visible wavelengths of light (Si band gap is 1.1eV). It is of no help to you, but I vaguely recall seeing that photo years ago- a dim red light, if I recall correctly. It's complicated by the opacity of Si to visible light, so the junction must have been exposed. The phenomenon can be (indirectly) observed in small signal Si transistors.

Interestingly, CMOS transistors emit a faint light which can be used as a kind of ideal (in the sense it does not affect the circuit) current probe to directly measure timing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one to guess. There are two possible answers. First, it is possible that it could be emitting light because it has been overloaded, or used abnormally. That would be my guess.

However, there are [transistors that are designed to emit light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_light-emitting_transistor). These are not common, but it is possible that it was a picture of one of these.

Hard to say really :-|