# Light emiting transistors?

Tags: transistors

It's crazy idea, but i wondering if it's possible to build some blinking multivibrator circuit without any leds, where transistors emit light themselves, it would be cool :)

I googled and it seems perspective technology for oled displays, but does LETs exist in standalone packages like LEDs?

I found interesting topic here [Why do some power transistors emit light?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/99125/why-do-some-power-transistors-emit-light)

So if i buy some of GaAs (it has wider bandgap, so could emit visible light, yes? ) fets like these
http://www.ebay.com/itm/MGF0906B-Manu-MITSUBISHI-Encapsulation-RF-TRANSISTOR-L-S-BAND-POWER-GaAs-FET-/121483823465?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c49000969
and break their ceramic package without damaging transistor itself, would i see any visible light?

Comment: Look up the maximum current for the transistor, then double it and you've got a light emitting transistor.

Comment: The "without damaging the transistor itself" gets hard. But also read the answers: these transistors were operated outside their SOA.

Comment: I have read answers. And this 

>In old textbooks I've seen microscope photos of MOSFET dies emitting infrared. During linear operation (pinch-off) the FET channel is experiencing constant avalanche breakdown, and it emits a tiny bit of IR light.


seems interesting. So i wondering if i'll take GaAs fet will there by any visible light?

Comment: (Assuming you can find a GaAs FET in packaging that doesn't block visible light) -- Wouldn't a *light-emitting* junction also be *sensitive* to receiving ambient light? For an LED that's not an issue, but for a BJT or a FET, it might interfere with the intended operation.

Comment: Hm, maybe i can try it the dark?
Probably i won't find fet in transparent package, i think there is some space between ceramic package of transistor and it's crystal, so i could try to break pakage without damaging crystal. But i want to know if it worth trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. FETs don't conduct current the same way as BJTs (NPNs, PNPs) do. They are majority carrier devices, which basically means that there isn't a current flowing across a PN junction.

Even if you could, GaAs transistors are not engineered to be efficient light emitters, and wouldn't emit in the visible region. You wouldn't see anything.

PN junctions do emit some photons when carriers are recombining, but the levels are extremely low, and not practical.